# Calculating a parameter dynamically based on the input in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to write a SQL Server stored procedure where based on the input date given by the user, data needs to be calculated dynamically.

To explain in detail, I need to find the sum of weights recorded from start of a month till the input date in the database.

The data will be recorded in DB during each shift for each day.

A day consists of 3 shifts. So number of shifts will be 3*30=90 (for a 30 days month).

Here is where it gets tricky. My query needs to be such that, the number of shifts should be calculated dynamically based on the input date.

For example, if the input date is 20, then no.of shifts will be 3*20=60 (from 1st day of the month to input day).

This number of shifts will be used to calculate the total average weight recorded for that month.

```
[Sum of weights from 1st day till input day] 
      / [no. of shifts from first day of month till input day]
```

I am providing part of my stored procedure that is relevant to this question. I can find the number of days from start date to input date, but I am unable to calculate the number of shifts based on the input date.

```
    @Reportdate DATETIME,

SELECT 
    PartName,
    (SUM((COALESCE(weightActualPerCent, 0))) / 'total shifts') AS 'OverWeight%'
FROM 
    table1
WHERE 
    Process = 'Cooling'
    AND Day >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Reportdate), 0) 
    AND Day < @Reportdate;
```

In the above code, the denominator 'total shifts' should be calculated dynamically based on the number of days between start date and input date. Any suggestions/pointers will be much appreciated.

Apologies if the question was too lengthy or confusing.

Comment: You already have an expression for a month start day `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @Reportdate), 0) ` . So you just need DATEDIFF from start to input date in days  `DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @Reportdate), 0), @Reportdate)`   and multiply by 3 shifts a day.

Comment: Thank you. I was so confused on how to implement it, that I didnt notice the expression for month start day in my query.. Was able to complete this logic with your help :)